# Ao compilar uma classe herdada em C++ dá erro no construtor

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, herança, construtor

Preciso criar uma classe para peças de xadrez. Criei a classe `Peca` e a derivada dela, `Bispo`.

Quando eu tento compilar a classe bispo, o compilador retorna erro de redefinição. Como posso resolver?

```
#ifndef PECA_H
#define PECA_H
#include <string>

using std::string;

class Peca {

    private:
        int cor; //0 para as brancas, 1 para as pretas
        bool emJogo;

    public:
        Peca(int cor);
        string desenha();
        bool checaMovimento(int linhaOrigem, int colunaOrigem, int linhaDestino, int colunaDestino);
        int getCor();
        bool estaEmJogo();
        void setForaDeJogo(bool estado);
};
#endif
```

Peca.h

```
#include "Peca.h"

using std::string;

class Bispo: public Peca {
    public:
        Bispo(int cor): Peca(cor);
        bool checaMovimento(int linhaOrigem, int colunaOrigem, int linhaDestino, int colunaDestino);
        string desenha();
};
```

Bispo.h

```
#include "Bispo.h"
#include <cmath>

Bispo::Bispo(int cor): Peca(cor){};

bool Bispo::checaMovimento(int linhaOrigem, int colunaOrigem, int linhaDestino, int colunaDestino)
{
    if (abs(linhaDestino - linhaOrigem) == abs(colunaDestino - colunaOrigem))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

//Minúsculo para peças brancas, maiúsculo para as peças pretas
string Bispo::desenha()
{
    if(getCor() == 0) // Peça branca
        return("b");
    else
        return("B");
}
```

Bispo.cpp

[image: Erro do compilador]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na declaração da classe o método não deve ter implementação e você colocou um inicializador, tem que tirar:

```
class Bispo: public Peca {
    public:
        Bispo(int cor);
        bool checaMovimento(int linhaOrigem, int colunaOrigem, int linhaDestino, int colunaDestino);
        string desenha();
};
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Syntax/ConstructorImplementation.cpp).

Comment: Muito obrigado!